# React native 0.61.2 Alert.alert not working on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, alert, native

I have noticed some odd behavior i have a Logout Dialog in place which has a Alert.alert in it for android & ios both.

```
import { Alert } from react-native

logOut() {

console.log("========LOGOUT============");

Alert.alert(
  'Log out',
  'Are you sure you want to logout?',
  [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {
      text: 'Yes',
      onPress: () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
      },
    },
  ],

  {cancelable: false},
);
```

}

**Scenario # 1** 
Alert does not work.

```
npm start and react-native run-android
```

**Scenario # 2**

Alert works ( for some reasons ) but assets does not show( that makes sense as i haven't started the metro server ) but Alert works.

```
react-native run-android
```

**Scenario # 3**
Alert does not work again.

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

log print when running metro server but alert is not shown.

Here's what i have tried :- 
Upgrading my **react-native to 0.61.4** and it does not work.
followed a lot of tutorials and seems it is pretty straight forward and it should have been but the problem persist on my side.

react-native info ( that's after i moved it to RN 0.61.5 )

```
 npmPackages:
    react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0 
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

*Update* 
I have similar alert code on my login.js and it shows the alert in that screen ( Invalid email or password ) but not any where else once i login in to my app.

Thank you for any help and let me know if you guys need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was occurring due to `react-native-drawer`
(which is no longer maintained now).

I used `react-navigation-drawer` this what I should have used from the start but for some reason I didn't.

If anyone faces this type of issue
go through the components one by one and figure out which messes up.